# Passing values or References through functions

Tags: c++

This is a question of style or correctness for C++.

Say you have functionA and functionB, is it correct or good style to pass a value to functionA which it doesn't need itself, but needs to know about it to call functionB, which it(functionA) calls later?

I can't refer directly to the values as they are declared inside main.

Comment: I think it depends on your software design.

Comment: You could consider an object-oriented design and store the value as a member variable in a class and then have `functionA` and `functionB` as member functions on your class. Then you don't need to pass the value through the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `functionB` needs the value then, effectively, `functionA` *does* need it. Therefore, it should be passed as a parameter to `functionA`.

If you're worried about creating value copies, you could always pass it by reference or constant reference.

Answer (score 0):

Think about an interface that encapsulates that calls `functionB`

Answer (score 0):

A common convention for large variables in C++ is the use of pointers. To save resources, you can initialize a pointer to a variable on the heap using `new` like so: `int *num = new int;` This way you're not passing around a big array - for example - and instead, pass around the hex address of that array in memory.